# How to put "large" image and "small" image into one folder - Caroufredsel Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

I want to put the thumbnail image into one folder with the large image. What should I change in my script?

I don't understand with this sintax

```
src = src.split( '/large/' ).join( '/small/' );
```

I've tried to make some modification, but these still don't works.

Here the link of the slider that I use:

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/61/

```
$(function() {
        var $carousel = $('#carousel'),
          $pager = $('#pager');

        function getCenterThumb() {
          var $visible = $pager.triggerHandler( 'currentVisible' ),
            center = Math.floor($visible.length / 2);

          return center;
        }

        $carousel.carouFredSel({
          responsive: true,
          items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: 1600,
            height: 'auto'
          },
          scroll: {
            fx: 'crossfade',
            onBefore: function( data ) {
              var src = data.items.visible.first().attr( 'src' );
              src = src.split( '/large/' ).join( '/small/' );

              $pager.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]', -getCenterThumb() ] );
              $pager.find( 'img' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
            },
            onAfter: function() {
              $pager.find( 'img' ).eq( getCenterThumb() ).addClass( 'selected' );
            }
          }
        });
        $pager.carouFredSel({
          width: '100%',
          auto: false,
          height: 120,
          items: {
            visible: 'odd'
          },
          onCreate: function() {
            var center = getCenterThumb();
            $pager.trigger( 'slideTo', [ -center, { duration: 0 } ] );
            $pager.find( 'img' ).eq( center ).addClass( 'selected' );
          }
        });
        $pager.find( 'img' ).click(function() {
          var src = $(this).attr( 'src' );
          src = src.split( '/small/' ).join( '/large/' );
          $carousel.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]' ] );
        });
      });
```

Comment: `I don't understand with this sintax src = src.split( '/large/' ).join( '/small/' );` - it's basically replace all occurrences of "/large/" with "/small/" in string `str`.

Comment: Hi @mishik what should I do to put the images and thumbnails into one folder? without large and small folder. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved!

I just remove the "/large/" and "/small/" in the script.

So, the script look like this now:

```
$(function() {
        var $carousel = $('#carousel'),
          $pager = $('#pager');

        function getCenterThumb() {
          var $visible = $pager.triggerHandler( 'currentVisible' ),
            center = Math.floor($visible.length / 2);

          return center;
        }

        $carousel.carouFredSel({
          responsive: true,
          items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: 1600,
            height: 'auto'
          },
          scroll: {
            fx: 'crossfade',
            onBefore: function( data ) {
              var src = data.items.visible.first().attr( 'src' );
              src = src.split( '' ).join( '' );

              $pager.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]', -getCenterThumb() ] );
              $pager.find( 'img' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
            },
            onAfter: function() {
              $pager.find( 'img' ).eq( getCenterThumb() ).addClass( 'selected' );
            }
          }
        });
        $pager.carouFredSel({
          width: '100%',
          auto: false,
          height: 120,
          items: {
            visible: 'odd'
          },
          onCreate: function() {
            var center = getCenterThumb();
            $pager.trigger( 'slideTo', [ -center, { duration: 0 } ] );
            $pager.find( 'img' ).eq( center ).addClass( 'selected' );
          }
        });
        $pager.find( 'img' ).click(function() {
          var src = $(this).attr( 'src' );
          src = src.split( '' ).join( '' );
          $carousel.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]' ] );
        });
      });
```